# Java : round a double to four decimals

Tags: java

I want to round a number to 4 decimals. I have done that :

```
roundedNumber =  (double)(Math.round(roundedNumber)*10000)/10000;
```

It doesn't work with a number such as : `0.20425` .
I am getting the following output: `0.0`

What should I do to get: `0.2042` ?

Comment: Do you need it for displaying, or do you actually need to round the number?

Comment: I need to round them.

Comment: You can't round doubles, but you could attempt to. In that case the parentheses are wrong: `roundedNumber =  (double)(Math.round(roundedNumber*10000))/10000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mutiply *before* rounding:

```
roundedNumber = Math.round(roundedNumber*10000)/10000.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DecimalFormat`

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
double formatedNumber =  Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(0.20425));

System.out.println(formatedNumber);
```